# Primefaces remoteCommand not calling on Button onSuccess

Tags: jsf, remotecommand

In my form, I need to call two servlets with one button click. i want to call the `p:remoteCommand` after button action onsuccess.But the remote Command is not calling .

**XHTML:**

```
<p:commandButton value="Confirm" id="esubmit" onsuccess="printBothVoucherDO()"                                       actionListener="#{expenseController.saveExpense}" 
    update="@([id$=submittedVoucherspanel]) @([id$=msgs]) @([id$=expenseForm])"
    styleClass="_tab_submit" ></p:commandButton>

<p:remoteCommand name="printBothVoucherDO"
                                actionListener="#{expenseController.printBothDOVoucher}"></p:remoteCommand>
```

**Method calling**

```
public void printBothDOVoucher(ActionEvent event) {
        TmsUtil.executeOnPage("window.open('PrintVouchers" + "')");
        TmsUtil.executeOnPage("window.open('PrintDeliveryOrder" + "')");
    }
```

Comment: why put the control logic in the view? - why not have that operation done as one in server side?